# How to create a Spotify playlist using react?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, spotify, access-token

I am trying to create a playlist on localhost and then have the list I created to be saved to Spotify. Can someone help why **Save to Spotify** button might not be working? Everything else seems fine, I have doubts about the fetching part I used but can't figure out what the issue might be.

Screenshot of the page: 
[image]

And there is the Spotify.js code:

```
import { SearchBar } from '../components/SearchBar/SearchBar';

const clientId = 'I've put my client id';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback/';

let accessToken;
const Spotify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    }
    //check for access token match
    const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
    if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
      let expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
      //This clears the parameters, allowing to grab new access token then it expires
      window.setTimeout(() => (accessToken = ''), expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
      return accessToken;
    } else {
      const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
      window.location = accessUrl;
    }
  },
  search(term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
          return [];
        }
        return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map((track) => ({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          artists: track.artists[0].name,
          album: track.album.name,
          uri: track.uri,
        }));
      });
  },
  savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
    if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
      return;
    }
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    let userId;

    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, { headers: headers })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => (userId = jsonResponse.id))
      .then((userId) => {
        return fetch(`/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
          headers: headers,
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((jsonResponse) => {
            const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(`/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`, {
              headers: headers,
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({ uris: trackUris }),
            });
          });
      });
  },
};

export default Spotify;
```

Here is the screenshot of Element > Console: 
[image]

Comment: what's the error you get in the network tab in the console?

Comment: Just added, thank you for looking into @ludwiguer

Comment: I can't see any network request, where are you calling your `savePlaylist` method?

Comment: @ludwiguer In App.js file, I've passed it to Playlist component : <Playlist onSave={this.savePlaylist} /> and before that still in App.js I've defined savePlaylist() {
    let trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map((track) => track.uri);
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
      this.setState({ playlistName: 'New Playlist', playlistTracks: [] });
    });
  }

Comment: can you try to put a catch in your fetch and log into the console the error if any

Comment: Also maybe putting the part of the App.js file where you're calling the savePlaylist could be useful

Answer (score 0):

I had an fetch error, updated as below and working now.

```
let accessToken;
const Spotify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    }
    //check for access token match
    const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
    if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
      let expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
      //This clears the parameters, allowing to grab new access token then it expires
      window.setTimeout(() => (accessToken = ''), expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
      return accessToken;
    } else {
      const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
      window.location = accessUrl;
    }
  },
  search(term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
          return [];
        }
        return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map((track) => ({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          artists: track.artists[0].name,
          album: track.album.name,
          uri: track.uri,
        }));
      });
  },
  savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
    if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
      return;
    }

    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    let userID;

    return fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', { headers: headers })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        userID = jsonResponse.id;
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userID}/playlists`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: headers,
          body: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((jsonResponse) => {
            const playlistID = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(
              `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userID}/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`,
              {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify({ uris: trackUris }),
              }
            );
          });
      });
  }, // end of savePlaylist method
}; // end of Spotify object

export default Spotify;
```